# getting the right amount of beers for each email in database

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie in programming and just started with a project. My question is how should the query look like to get the right data?
My table:

```
id      rfid      beer            email 
1      12345      3             markus.test@gmail.com
2      54321      4             hans.test@gmail.com
3      63737      1             mark.test@gmail.com
4      12345     -2             markus.test@gmail.com
5      54321     -3             hans.test@gmail.com
```

The query result should look like

```
[{email: markus.test@gmail.com, beer:1},{email:hans.test@gmail.com, beer:1}....]
```

I know that you can use SUM(beer) in the query, but I don't know who to match them with the right email.

Answer (score 0):

If you group your data then aggregate functions like `sum()` will sum for each group and not the complete result

```
select email, sum(beer) as beer
from your_table
group by email
```